# Jquery mobile changePage deleting dynamic html

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working on some code that has dynamically created html pages for jquery mobile. I'm having an issue with changing the page because $.mobile.changePage is deleting all the dynamic pages except for the one it is changing to?

There really isn't much code...

```
$.mobile.loadPage(self.path).done(function (e, ui, page)
        {
            self.loadJavascript();
            self.generatedHtml = $(self.id);
            self.makeActive(self.defaultTransition);
        });

$.mobile.changePage(id, {transition: transitionString})
```

How do you prevent jquery mobile from deleting other pages when you use the changePage function?